# Typing degree symbol in Chrome goes back instead

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome version: 13.0.782.112 m

Attempting to type the degree symbol: ° (alt-0176) anywhere in Chrome causes the browser to invoke its back or previous page function, instead of staying on the same page and inserting the symbol.

Typing the same sequence in other applications (notepad++, visual studio 2010) performs normally as one would expect.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my Chrome install - I get a degree symbol: °°°

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Turn NUM LOCK on!

I am typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> in Chrome: °

You can go back to a prior URL in Chrome by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> but I don't think you can easily mistype one for the other with a normal keyboard layout **Unless you have NUM-LOCK off!**

If you **have NUM LOCK off** pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> which takes you to your home page. Then pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> which takes you forward a page.

Comment: Good Lord, it was numlock.  Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I type:

<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (option zero) to get º.

On my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9 Build 13C64 and 
Chrome Version 37.0.2062.94

---